# scp all log files of pattern filename_date between 2 dates in shell script

Tags: linux, server, sh, scp

My log file is in the format `upd_yyyymmdd_slr.stats`. I want to copy all files from a server to my local server between 2 dates, for example.

I want all files having dates in log file as `20151228` and `20160103` means I want to copy the below files from a set of many files.

```
upd_20151228_slr.stats
upd_20151229_slr.stats
upd_20151230_slr.stats
upd_20151231_slr.stats
upd_20160101_slr.stats
upd_20160102_slr.stats
upd_20160103_slr.stats
```

I'm using the below command but it is not working

```
 scp server:/reports/logs/upd_20[15-16][12-01][29-03]*slr* ./log_files
```

Please find me the best way I can do in Linux as well as in shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ls upd_*_slr.stats`; do 
  # First strip off prefix and suffix strings.
  s=`echo $i | sed 's/upd_//g' | sed 's/_slr.stats//g'`
  if [[ $s -ge 20151230 && $s -le 20160102 ]]; then # Modify dates as needed 
    echo $i
    cp $i /path/to/dest/dir
  fi
done
```

**EDIT:**

In case of a remote server one could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `ssh username@remoteaddress ls /path/to/dir/upd_*_slr.stats`; do 
  i=${i##*/}
  # First strip off extra strings leaving only date.
  s=`echo $i | sed 's/upd_//g' | sed 's/_slr.stats//g'`
  if [[ $s -ge 20151230 && $s -le 20160102 ]]; then # Modify dates as needed 
    echo $i
    scp username@remoteaddress:/path/to/dir/$i /path/to/dest/dir
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hi ottoshmidt Please suggest as this will work if i wanna copy the files from the on the same server from one location to another.But i wanna copy from 1 server to another.Like i m logged in from abc.x.com and i wanna copy from qwe.x.com then how can i scp that.

Comment: made 5 files and run this code as it as getting error wen i run this code only ->shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found
shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found
shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found
shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found
shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found
shellt.sh: 6: shellt.sh: [[: not found

Comment: It's a bash script it might not run if you run it with shell (sh). Also, make sure there is a space before and after [[ and ]] brackets.

Comment: Added code for accessing remote server. See EDIT part in the above answer.